# Is 4 pin 12v connector necessary in my motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, upgrade, computer-building

I am building my new PC. I am really a newbie at this.
Currently I have SIEMENS D1107 motherboard. I want to replace it with HP P4SD motherboard.
But there is a one problem. The new motherboard has 4 pin 12v connector but my PSU doesn`t have it.
Is this connector necessary, will my motherboard work without it and if it do work, what problems are expected?

**EDIT**

I have tried to start system without that wire, but power led does not turning on, and PC shutdowns itself. :)

I don`t need to buy a new PSU. I can buy an adapter like this one:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if it is there, it is necessary, and I doubt you will even get past the POST test (probably will beep). Even if it somehow worked, you could expect strange problems at times due to lack of power related to that not being plugged in. I would also worry about causing permanent damage.

Comment: OK, I did not know about that converter cable, so I edited that out.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about permanent damage, but you're asking for trouble by not providing power where requested.